# How to cast an explicit named lambda argument in kotlin mapping functions

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, vert.x

Given a functor of a generic `Any` type, how can I cast an explicity named argument? For instance, I have a JsonArray (vertx) that is essentially a type of `List<Any>`... I can cast to `JsonObject` using the implicit `it`, but if I were to name it `participant` how can I cast as JsonObject?

```kotlin
val participants = conversation
    .getJsonArray("participants")
    .map{ (it as JsonObject)
        it.getInteger("id")
    }
```

My IDE complains no matter what I throw at it. Is this even possible? Something like:

```kotlin
val participants = conversation
    .getJsonArray("participants")
    .map{ (participant as JsonObject) ->
        participant.getInteger("id")
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `.map{ (it as JsonObject).getInteger("id") }`?

Comment: @gidds Yes, that works, but sometimes I want to name `it` explicitly like `participant` to disambiguate nested mapping function `its`... but `(participant as JsonObject)` doesnt compile.

Answer (score 1):

Like @gidds wrote, following is correct:

```kotlin
val participants = conversation
    .getJsonArray("participants")
    .map { 
       (it as JsonObject).getInteger("id")
    }
```

For explicit arguments you can write like this:

```kotlin
val participants = conversation
    .getJsonArray("participants")
    .map { participant -> 
       (participant as JsonObject).getInteger("id")
    }
```